# rfkill command not found

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I'm using Kali on my Raspberry pi
I am trying to use airmon-ng but I'm getting the error

```
root@kali:~/downloads# airmon-ng
Your kernel supports rfkill but you don't have rfkill installed.

To ensure devices are unblocked you must install rfkill.

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

null    wlan0           ??????          Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

How do I install rfkill or how else would I avoid this error

I've tried sudo apt-get install rfkill and I got this error

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install rfkill
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rfkill
```

Comment: Like any other software, `apt-get install rfkill`

Comment: @deviantfan I've updated the problem

Comment: But it's there: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/r/rfkill/ . What's in your /etc/apt/sources.list file? Did you ever do a `apt-get update` before on this installation?

Comment: @deviantfan running apt-get update fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade` fixed the problem