# How to configure hotspot with wifi dongle DWA-131 in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, hotspot

I've tried this tutorial https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf to make a Hotspot in Kali Linux, but when i try to run hostapd with this configuration, i got the following error

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl8192eu
ssid=GORIO_AP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=gorio1234
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

this is the error

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'rtl8192eu'
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to initialize interface
```

My dmesg log is

```
$ dmesg | grep usbcore
[    0.524513] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.524526] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.524552] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.518790] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.977948] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    4.138575] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192eu
```

My ifconfig output is

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 54:2a:a2:77:1f:30  
          UP BROADCASTMULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:261 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Command **lsmod**

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uas                    24576  0 
usb_storage            61440  1 uas
bnep                   20480  2 
cfg80211              454656  0 
nfnetlink_queue        24576  0 
nfnetlink_log          20480  0 
nfnetlink              16384  2 nfnetlink_log,nfnetlink_queue
bluetooth             425984  5 bnep
rfkill                 20480  5 cfg80211,bluetooth
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1 
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1 
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 20480  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv4      20480  2 
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  1 
nf_conntrack           94208  5 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter         16384  1 
ip_tables              28672  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               28672  4 ip_tables,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter
8192eu                884736  0
iTCO_wdt               16384  0 
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
ppdev                  20480  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
coretemp               16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
kvm_intel             151552  0 
dcdbas                 16384  0 
i915                 1015808  4 
kvm                   425984  1 kvm_intel
psmouse               110592  0 
snd_hda_intel          28672  3 
serio_raw              16384  0 
drm_kms_helper        102400  1 i915
snd_hda_controller     28672  1 snd_hda_intel
pcspkr                 16384  0 
drm                   274432  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_codec         110592  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
lpc_ich                24576  0 
cdc_acm                32768  12 
snd_pcm                90112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
evdev                  24576  8 
8250_fintek            16384  0 
mfd_core               16384  1 lpc_ich
i2c_i801               20480  0 
video                  20480  1 i915
parport_pc             28672  0 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
parport                36864  2 ppdev,parport_pc
mei_me                 20480  0 
snd                    69632  14 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
mei                    77824  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
shpchp                 32768  0 
processor              28672  0 
button                 16384  1 i915
thermal_sys            32768  4 video,intel_powerclamp,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
fuse                   90112  7 
autofs4                36864  2 
ext4                  499712  1 
crc16                  16384  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                20480  1 ext4
jbd2                   86016  1 ext4
dm_mod                 94208  0 
sr_mod                 24576  0 
cdrom                  49152  1 sr_mod
sg                     32768  0 
sd_mod                 45056  6 
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 49152  0 
ata_generic            16384  0 
hid                   106496  2 hid_generic,usbhid
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
crc32c_intel           24576  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
r8169                  77824  0 
mii                    16384  1 r8169
aesni_intel           167936  0 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
ata_piix               36864  4 
ehci_pci               16384  0 
libata                180224  2 ata_generic,ata_piix
ehci_hcd               77824  1 ehci_pci
scsi_mod              200704  6 sg,uas,usb_storage,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
usbcore               200704  9 uas,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,8192eu,cdc_acm
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
```

**Command not found**

```
rfkill list
bash: rfkill: command not found
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong in my implementation or how to fix it ?

Comment: the driver there isn't talking about the NIC driver, but type of interface hostapd uses to talk to the that. usually you just need to set it to `nl80211` (or just leave out that option). see [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/hostapd) for details.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1014334/rfkill-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

The wifi driver is not correct because it is not included in the linux kernel. You will need to get it yourself. Here's a fix that worked for someone else:

1) Change the driver in /opt/piratebox/conf/hostapd to "rtl871xdrv"

2) Then replace the hostapd:

```
wget http://www.adafruit.com/downloads/adafruit_hostapd.zip 
unzip adafruit_hostapd.zip 
sudo mv /usr/sbin/hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd.ORIG 
sudo mv hostapd /usr/sbin
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/hostapd
```

[Further information on setting up a wireless hotspot on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-raspberry-pi-as-wireless-access-point/).

Apocrypha: I do not think you are going to have great luck using this wifi dongle with Kali. Getting it to run as a hotspot should work, but users generally report poor performance with Realtek chips when it comes to injection and other pentesting behaviors.